Perform an Update and Insert in a Delta Lake Merge Operation for the Same Rows
I'm  trying to perform an update and an insert operation on the same rows from a new DataFrame during a merge operation using Delta Tables via the delta-rs Python package. My goal is to:
Update the existing rows in the target table if they match a condition.
Insert new rows into the target table based on the same matched condition.
Delta Lake does not support a whenMatchedInsert method, but a similar tool is exactly what I need.
Here's a simplified version of the code I attempted:
(
    target_table.alias("existing")
    .merge(
        new_data.alias("new"),
        "existing.id = new.id
    )
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        condition="existing.state != new.state",
        set={"end_time": "new.start_time"}  # Update Old State using New State
    )
    .whenMatchedInsert(  # This method does not exist
        condition="existing.state != new.state",  # Insert New State
        set={"end_time": "new.start_time"}
    )
    .execute()
)


Separating this into two statements does not work because both the update and the insert operations rely on the state of the table before it is operated upon. And persisting the matching data won't work because when a source table is modified, its caches are flushed
How can I achieve both the update and insert operations for the same matched rows? Is there an alternative approach or workaround that I can use to handle this scenario?
I have seen other posts about taking advantage of delta table versioning, which may be a solution here, but seems overly intensive when compared to my intuitive approach above.
Any guidance or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

condition in merge should be existing.id = new.id and existing.state = new.state so it will insert new row if state is not matching

@AlexanderPavlov those rows are irrelevant. I am looking for a way to both update and insert rows matching the condition existing.id = new.id and existing.state != new.state
